# Word or phrase to describe increasing periods between attempting the same operation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, programming

I'm looking for a term (single word or phrase) that describes the trick in software development to (typically exponentially) increase time between successive attempts to do an action on a server, for example logging in.

- **Context to use the phrase in**
  With talking with other software developers about the design of Software API's and login screens.
- **Criteria for which the suggested phrase will be accepted**
  Any term that has prevalent use in current software development literature would do: it should be well-known piece of jargon.
- **Phrases I didn't like**
  A term I feel is not a *great* fit (but my best alternative so far) is "*Throttling*". It's not a great fit because it describes the overal speed with which interactions between client and server take place, whereas in my context I have as fast as possible interaction for the first (few) request(s), only decreasing response time after successive attempts.
- **[Searches] for a suitable phrase**
  Skimming page 1 and 2 of ["increased time between login attempts"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=increased%20time%20between%20login%20attempts) gave no useful results. I've also looked through an online thesaurus (synonyms, and antonyms-of-antonyms) but found no suitable phrase.

I've got a feeling I've heard a specific bit of jargon for exactly what I want to express, but fail to remember what it was.

Any suggestions?

Comment: At work we'd likely refer to this as **extending the timeout**.

Comment: Are you referring to **turnaround time** by any chance?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy I believe he's referring specifically to the act of making the time longer, rather than the time itself.

Comment: @Jeroen If you're after a more "nouny" version, why not **timeout extension**?

Comment: Related: [*If (something) starts happening less often we say the **interval** is increasing*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/162611/2637) (the opposite of the ***rate*** increasing).

Comment: In the networking world, this is known as [***exponential backoff](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.3-2008_section1.pdf)***. Of course, that only applies in your scenario if your backoff is actually exponential. Otherwise it's just increasing, or even [strictly] monotonically increasing.

Comment: @Jeroen - In networking,  "latency" is used to refer to the time delay between processing instructions. I am not sure what the precise answer to your question is but I am just gonna give you - "lantesify"! (latency + intensify) :P

Comment: Retry Strategy? http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.4 Note the expression "back off" is used in this doc too, so I am going with @DanBron on this one.

Answer (score 2):

`Rate limiting` describes enforcing only a certain number of attempts per unit of time. `Progressive rate limiting` describes decreasing the number of allowed attempts per the same unit of time.